# append checkbox value corresponding text field in ajax jquery

Tags: ajax

i want to insert text box value which opens when click the check box.how to append check box value in ajax.itried below code but it is showing Unexpected token

```
formData.append('monday', $('input[name="monday"]:checked').val() == 'monday' ? $('[name="tmonday"]').val());
```